# geopy.distance.geodesic() but it says TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'tuple'

Tags: python, coordinates, typeerror, distance, geopy

I'm new and don't understand things. I want to make a new list of distances between every coordinates I have, a list of the distances of point1-point2, point1-point3, point2-point3.

so my code is:

`list_of_coords = [(5.55, 95.3175), (3.583333, 98.666667), (-0.95556, 100.36056)]`

`list_of_distances = [geopy.distance.geodesic(combo).km for combo in combinations(list_of_coords,2)]`

anddd when I try to run it, it says:

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'tuple'`

How to make it run properly? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can see in the [documentation](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html?highlight=distance.geodesic#geopy.distance.geodesic), `geodesic` takes multiple arguments, like `*args`.

So try unpacking:

```
list_of_distances = [geopy.distance.geodesic(*combo).km for combo in combinations(list_of_coords, 2)]
```

Or unpack iteration:

```
list_of_distances = [geopy.distance.geodesic(a, b).km for a, b in combinations(list_of_coords, 2)]
```